# What's the difference between HMAC-SHA256(key, data) and SHA256(key + data)

Tags: hmac

Is there anything different about how secure these two hashing algorithms are? Does HMAC "fuse" the data and the key in a special way that's more security-aware?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code

Comment: Related question: [Why is H(k||x) not a secure MAC construction?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/why-is-hkx-not-a-secure-mac-construction)

Answer (score 69):

Yes, HMAC is more complex than simple concatenation.

As a simplistic example, if you were to simply concatenate key + data, then "key1"+"data" yields identical results to "key"+"1data", which is suboptimal.  HMAC will yield different results for each.  There are other flaws with simple concatenation in many cases, as well; see cpast's answer for one.

The specification for HMAC is called [RFC2104](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt), which you should read if you have this level of interest.

In summary, to implement HMAC, you should first:

Create "ipad", which is `0x36` repeated BLOCKSIZE times.
Create "opad", which is `0x5c` repeated BLOCKSIZE times.

- Note that BLOCKSIZE is 64 bytes for MD5, SHA-1, SHA-224, SHA-256, and 128 bytes for SHA-384 and SHA-512, per [RFC2104](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt) and [RFC4868](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4868.txt).

Then HMAC is defined as:

```
HASH(Key XOR opad, HASH(Key XOR ipad, text))
```

or, in detail from the RFC,

> *(Pretext: The definition of HMAC requires a cryptographic hash function, which
>   we denote by H, and a secret key K. We assume H to be a cryptographic
>   hash function where data is hashed by iterating a basic compression
>   function on blocks of data.   We denote by B the byte-length of such
>   blocks.)*

```
(1) append zeros to the end of K to create a B byte string
    (e.g., if K is of length 20 bytes and B=64, then K will be
     appended with 44 zero bytes 0x00)
(2) XOR (bitwise exclusive-OR) the B byte string computed in step
    (1) with ipad
(3) append the stream of data 'text' to the B byte string resulting
    from step (2)
(4) apply H to the stream generated in step (3)
(5) XOR (bitwise exclusive-OR) the B byte string computed in
    step (1) with opad
(6) append the H result from step (4) to the B byte string
    resulting from step (5)
(7) apply H to the stream generated in step (6) and output
    the result
```

Answer (score 37):

There's actually a very big problem with `SHA256(key||data)`: SHA-256, along with SHA-512, SHA-1, MD5, and all other hashes using the Merkle–Damgård construction, is vulnerable to a [length extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack) attack: given `H(x)`, it's very simple to find `H(x||y)`, even if you only know the length of `x`, because of how the construction works.

(Essentially, the construction works like this: You have a variable `state` that starts at some fixed value specified in the algorithm. You split the input to the hash function into blocks of size specified in the algorithm (padding the last block if it's too short), and for each block, you use the current block and the current `state` to compute the new `state` using some special function specified in the algorithm. The value of `state` after processing the last block is the hash value. With any function using this construction, if you have the length of `x`, you can compute the padding `p` used. Then if you have `H(x)`, you have the state after processing every block of `x||p`, which means you can proceed from there to compute `H(x||p||y)`).

That means that an attacker who knows the *length* of your MAC key and knows a particular value of `SHA256(key||data)` can easily compute `SHA256(key||data||otherdata)` for some given `otherdata`. They can choose most of the other data, but even if they couldn't, it's a fatal flaw in a MAC scheme if an attacker without the key can forge *any* MAC-data pair from other legitimate MAC-data pairs.

Incidentally, `SHA256(data||key)`, while not vulnerable to length extension, is vulnerable to collisions in `SHA256`, which can also produce collisions in the proposed MAC, due to the same iterated construction. HMAC's nesting prevents these and various other attacks. With non-Merkle-Damgård hashes, you don't necessarily need the HMAC construction, though.

Comment: For SHA256(data||key), both the data and the key you mentioned were fixed length, right? If not, SHA256(data||otherdata||key) is still feasible I would suppose?